# Update user with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I would like to find a user by their phone number and update their `displayName` in Firebase Cloud Functions using the Admin SDK. 
When I try to run this code for example:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phone).then((user) => {
   user.displayName = newName;
}).catch((reason) => console.log(reason['message']));
```

I get the following message:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'displayName' of object '#UserRecord'

Although I undestand this exception, I cannot think of a diffrent way to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`getUserByPhoneNumber()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#get-user-byphone-number) method returns a [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html) which doesn't have any method to modify the `user` object.

You need to use the [`updateUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#update-user) method to do so, as follows:

```
//....
return admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phone)
.then(userRecord => {
   return admin.auth().updateUser(userRecord.uid, {displayName: newName});
})
.catch((reason) => console.log(reason['message']));
```

---

Don't forget to return the Promise chain if your Cloud Function is a background-triggered one, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions